# Is it possible make the pod reach inside the Hangar 21?

Tags: battlefield-4

In The Final Stand trailer transport pod is launched and lands inside the Hangar 21. I've tried that numerous times and it always lands short. Is it at all possible like in the trailer, or is it just scripted and not possible in the actual game?
(skip to 1:50)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do I've seen it done before but not quite as far in as in the trailer, I do believe they nerfed it at some point as it did propel you as far any more, it requires a great deal of precision to get it into the hanger.